# JavaScript this-keyword and context

Tags: javascript, html, this

https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trygame_canvas

I was looking at the js code from the tutorial in the link above, I understand mostly what's happening except for the line

```
this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Where does this.context come from? surely the word "this" is referring to the myGameArea object and then context is suppose to be some property of myGameArea, but it hasn't been defined. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That line is defining `.context`.

Comment: You're correct in that 'this' refers to myGameArea (which is an object). Objects can be expanded dynamically in Javascript. The line you mention is actually defining myGameArea.context.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work/3127440#3127440)

Answer (score 1):

That line is precisely defining the `context` property. Once you have an object, you can add properties to it that way: `this.context = ...`.

I recommend you to take a look to this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects
Will for sure explain many things.

Answer (score 0):

In loosely typed languages you are able to define properties of objects on runtime. It's pretty magic and allows for some pretty crazy stuff.

All that line does is set the context property to this.canvas.getContext("2d").

PHP works in a similiar way :)

Comment: hmm ok! So context is still a property of myGameArea and can be accessed as myGameArea.context ?